# Remove unicode string and spaces from json response using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, unicode

I am posting a data to a REST API and as a response I am receiving the data as a json response. This response having a unicode characters.
I tried many approaches to remove the unicode character from my json data but nothing worked :( and after the removal of unicode charaters I am validating the schema.
Following is my code snippet:

```
import json
import logging
from jsonschema import validate

if __name__ == '__main__':

    schema = {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "SOURCE": {
            "type": "string"
            },
            "TIMESTAMP": {
            "type": "string"
            },
            "TAGERRORS": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": [
                {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "TAGNAME": {
                     "type": "string"
                     },
                    "ERROR": {
                    "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "TAGNAME",
                    "ERROR"
                ]
                }
            ]
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "SOURCE",
            "TIMESTAMP",
            "TAGERRORS"
        ]
    }

    response_dict ='"{\\u000d\\u000a  \\"SOURCE\\": \\"APPDEV\\",\\u000d\\u000a  \\"TIMESTAMP\\": \\"2022-04-19 12:29:27\\",\\u000d\\u000a  \\"TAGERRORS\\": []\\u000d\\u000a}"'
    response_dict = response_dict.replace("\\u000d\\u000a\\s*", "")
    print(response_dict)
    my_json = json.loads(response_dict)
    # validate(instance=my_json, schema=schema)

    # print(my_json)
```

The `response_dict = response_dict.replace("\\u000d\\u000a\\s*", "")` is not working and giving the following result.
`"{\u000d\u000a  \"SOURCE\": \"APPDEV\",\u000d\u000a  \"TIMESTAMP\": \"2022-04-19 12:29:27\",\u000d\u000a  \"TAGERRORS\": []\u000d\u000a}"`
Also, I tried the following regex to remove the unicode characters but it failing during the schema validation.

```
import re

def removeunicode(text):
    text = re.sub(r'\\[u]\S\S\S\S[s]', "", text)
    text = re.sub(r'\\[u]\S\S\S\S', "", text)
    return text

my_json = json.loads(removeunicode(response_dict))
```

Can you please help to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: All characters are Unicode characters... Are you just wanting to remove the carriage returns and line feeds?

Comment: Maybe `re.sub( r"\\u000d\\u000a\s*", "", response_dict)`?

Comment: `str.replace` doesn't do regex matches like you're trying to do with `\s*`. Use `re.sub` if you need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is double-JSON-encoded.  Just `json.loads` the response twice to fix it, but if you can fix the upstream problem:

```py
# From OP's example
>>> response_dict ='"{\\u000d\\u000a  \\"SOURCE\\": \\"APPDEV\\",\\u000d\\u000a  \\"TIMESTAMP\\": \\"2022-04-19 12:29:27\\",\\u000d\\u000a  \\"TAGERRORS\\": []\\u000d\\u000a}"'
>>> print(response_dict)  # This is valid JSON
"{\u000d\u000a  \"SOURCE\": \"APPDEV\",\u000d\u000a  \"TIMESTAMP\": \"2022-04-19 12:29:27\",\u000d\u000a  \"TAGERRORS\": []\u000d\u000a}"
>>> json.loads(response_dict)
'{\r\n  "SOURCE": "APPDEV",\r\n  "TIMESTAMP": "2022-04-19 12:29:27",\r\n  "TAGERRORS": []\r\n}'
>>> json.loads(json.loads(response_dict))
{'SOURCE': 'APPDEV', 'TIMESTAMP': '2022-04-19 12:29:27', 'TAGERRORS': []}
```